# WPF Style in external file crashes

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, devexpress-wpf

I have a C# usercontrol with a DevExpress GridControl in it.
When I use a style for the GridColumns in the local xaml file like below, everything works

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <Style x:Key="K2M_GridColumn" TargetType="{x:Type dxg:GridColumn}">
            <Setter Property="AllowBestFit" Value="True" />
            <Setter Property="AllowColumnFiltering" Value="False" />
            <Setter Property="AllowEditing" Value="False" />
            <Setter Property="AllowSorting" Value="False" />
        </Style>

        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/RefImpl.Common.Client;component/Controls/Styles.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

If I move the above GridColumn style into the Styles.xaml the VS Designer breaks and shows this.

```
Exception: An error occurred while finding the resource dictionary "/RefImpl.Common.Client;component/Controls/Styles.xaml".
Error   XDG0012 The member "AllowBestFit" is not recognized or is not accessible.
Error   XDG0012 The member "AllowColumnFiltering" is not recognized or is not accessible.
...
```

If I remove the GridColumn style from Styles.xaml everything compiles and works, except that I don't have the style ofc.
So as long as I don't add the GridColumn style to the Styles.xaml file everything works.

I have defined this at the top in both the local xaml file and the Styles.xaml file

```
xmlns:dxg="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/grid"
```

Any suggestions on what's causing the error?

Comment: Try to switch Target Framework for the project to the higher version. It can be, that there is a discrepancy between .Net Framework versions.

Comment: Is this a designer issue only, i.e. does it work when you run the application?

Comment: It's not a designer only issue. The app crashes hard when the view with the style is created.

Comment: @Rekshino It was a missmatch between the DevExpress versions in my different projects, your comment pointed me in the right direction. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue! It was a mismatch of versions of DevExpress.
In the project with the xaml control I was using a older version of DevExpress and in the project with the Styles.xaml I was using a newer version of DevExpress.

For some unknown reason that causes a big runtime crash and Designer issues. No error messages though.